# Execute a condition if form values are not set in php

Tags: php, post, conditional-statements

I am trying a execute a piece of code if form values are not set, but it's not working properly.

Here is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="downloadreport.php">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">From  Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" > 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">To Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" > 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Select Usertype</label>
            <select name="trackforums" id="trackforumns" class="form-control" >     
                <option value="1">Active</option>
                <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                <option value="3">Active/Inactive</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info form-control">Download Report</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here are my form values

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fromdate =$_POST['datepicker'];
    $todate =  $_POST['datepicker1'];
    $usertype= $_POST['trackforums'];

    if($todate >= $fromdate) {
        //execute report with dates
    } elseif(isset($_POST[fromdate]) && $_POST[todate] = "") {
        //execute full report
    } else {
        echo "Your To date should be greater than from date";
    }
 }
```

When I have tried this, it is not going to the elseif condition if I didn't enter any dates in form field.

Comment: when i try with var_dump($_POST) getting like this  array(4) { ["datepicker"]=> string(0) "" ["datepicker1"]=> string(0) "" ["trackforums"]=> string(1) "1" ["submit"]=> string(6) "submit" }

Comment: Don't use comments to add details. Edit your post with important informations.

Comment: its a huge code inside conditions thats y i have kept like this

Comment: I mean your comment under question `when i try with var_dump($_POST)  .... ` Comments in code are fine, if all important details are left in question.

Comment: `$_POST[todate] = ""` doesn't check a value, it sets a value. It should be `$_POST[todate] == ""`.

Comment: ...and since an empty string is a "falsy" value, that expression will never be evaluated as true and that code block will never be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is delivering empty strings when the date values are missing; `empty()` can check that.  `empty()` offers the added benefit of checking for missing keys, so you won't get Notices.

Untested Suggested Condition Block:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "No submission";
} elseif (empty($_POST['datepicker']) || empty($_POST['datepicker1'])) {
    echo "at least one date picker is empty, treat as no dates picked";
} elseif ($_POST['datepicker1'] >= $_POST['datepicker']) {
    echo "invalid To date";
} else {
    echo "execute report within valid date range
}
```

Comment: yes i have looked at can  you please make your answer with only 3 conditions as per my question? as i am little bit confused with those conditions

Comment: I believe this improves your validation process.  What happens when `$_POST['datepicker']` is empty?  Do you execute something in this case?

Comment: No actually in my case if user want to download excel either they will enter both from and  todate orelse they wont enter any values in from and todate

Comment: You understand my problem rite?

Comment: For `_POST['datepicker1'] >= $_POST['datepicker']` to logically work, you need both date picker values to be "non-empty".  This is the reason for my first `elseif` check.

Comment: your conditions are working please make a comment on first elseif as full downlaod report and second elseif as download report with in date range and else as todate should be graeter than from date